# Infinite shell transformation in FEM

Tags: transformation, finite-element-method

I would like to know please, what would be the expression of the transformation matrix for an infinite shell transformation in FEM.
It's been really 4 years since I've had real math courses so I would appreciate it if you go easy on me please.
Also, does rotating a matrix refer to multiplying it by the rotation matrix?

Thanks in advance.